# GCP Application credentials stop working randomly

Tags: swift, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

So I am using dialogflow in my ios app. I have created a service account and have given the permission of owner to use it. I export the access token via terminal and use it in the app. It will work for some time and will start giving me 401 after some time. Could you please help me on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your Google cloud project is published. Otherwise if it is just in testing mode, authorization will expire after a week.

Comment: It doesn't even last a week. It expires in few hours but I'll give it a try.

Comment: you should also share more about your authentication scheme, as you may receive a refresh token that you need to use to renew access programmatically..

Comment: Don't use a token. Use a service account credential file and use the client library to generate the tokens from the app. However, for installed apps, instead of embedding service account credentials (which is generally discouraged), you probably want to use an oauth client and have the users logging into the app in order to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your Service Account make sure you aren't creating [short-lived service account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials) as this type of only lasts a couple of hours.

In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) you can find how to create service accounts, and [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) you can find how to grant access to the desired resources.